# Find in PouchDB with attachments

Tags: pouchdb

PouchDB allows to add attachments to documents. We can retrieve them by adding `attachments: true` when getting documents.

How can I do with the find functionality to query documents and retrieve them with their attachments? I do the following:

```
db.find({selector: {type:'question'}})
```

But the attachments are not included in the response.

Comment: From the docs, it appears this functionality is not supported by PouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PouchDB and the CouchDB documentation for find make no mention of attachments. If you need them, you should consider making a second `_all_docs` query using the `keys` from `find`.